# Is it possible to keep built-in GridTile styles when image preload is used?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

GridTile apply specofic styles to image in children prop. But when i use preload wrapper styles are not allpy [here's why](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/GridList/GridTile.js)

So can i pass GridTile styles to wrapped image without overriding?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see in the code [here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/GridList/GridTile.js#L225), styles are merged:

```
style: prepareStyles(Object.assign({}, styles.childImg, child.props.style))
```

but there are IF statements above that, so you need to fulfil those conditions as well:

- there must be only **one** child
- this child must be an `<img ... />`